# How to remove decimal in script in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I was trying to load bulk data from Excel into one Oracle table, so I tried with Oracle SQL Developer.

It generated an `INSERT` script for 20,0000 records. But the problem is I am getting NUMBER values with decimals like below:

```
INSERT INTO test_tb (FI_KEY, CL_KEY, ST_KEY, CL_NUMBER, YE, PA_NAME, RA_KEY, SH_KEY, B_NUMBER, FLAG, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, ACTIVE_STATUS) 
VALUES (691001.0, 1.0, 1.0, '387136', 2020.0, 'KUR', 370.0, 2221.0, 'J-12708', 'Y', 'admin', to_timestamp('03/11/2020', 'DD-MM-YY HH12:MI:SSXFF AM'), 'Y');
```

I want to get the `INSERT` script without decimal point for NUMBER values.

NOTE: These decimal values are not presented in Excel data but getting in INSERT script only.

Any one face this this or suggest any other method for bulk insert in SQL or in PL/SQL?

Comment: Can you check and confirm what is the DDL for the table and excel cell formats. That may resolve your issue

Comment: It doesn't matter. the `.0` won't really be stored in the database. There is nothing you need to do. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ff6cf897e4e21bd911f1af50b04cfcc0

Comment: @DeepakKumar How to check excel cell format?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes i too know that ```.0``` wont make any problem, but my script should not have that.

Comment: If it doesn't make a difference then why do you want to remove it? What is the problem you are trying to solve by removing something that doesn't change the outcome of the script?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My lead ask script like that.

Comment: Does your lead know that it won't make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you are to efficiently load big volumes of data from Excel, I would suggest turning the format of the Excel to CSV and using [sqlldr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm) There you could create a control file where you could adjust your data and perform TRUNC, ROUND and conditional processing.

Comment: Yaa, i too know about SQLLDR but, i dont have privilage for that to work.